# Automatic updates interval

Tags: 16.04, updates

As I know, `APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";` sets the days only.

How to set the time of automatic updates, for example, every day at 05:00 ?

The main thing is a time. It is necessary to do the update when the traffic on the site is minimal. Daily update it is just an example, but it can be useful for security updates.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain why running unattended-upgrades at the same time each day is a good idea for you. You are trying to defeat part of u-u's design. The developers would like to know about new use cases like yours.

Comment: @user535733 Look at last paragraph

Answer (score 0):

You could disable automatic updates all together and just write a cron job that checks for updates at a specific time.

The package cron-apt could be used if you want to automatically download updates when server load is low but review them before installation. More info here: https://debian-administration.org/article/162/A_short_introduction_to_cron-apt